# Centroid of svg path in blazor project c#

Tags: c#, html, svg

I'm trying to find the centroid (x, y coordinates) of an SVG path in C#. The SVG path is defined as follows:

```html
        <path id="myPath" fill="@GetColor(1, 16, @LeftInsolePressures[0])" d="M1185 8408 c-2 -7 -6 -277 -10 -599 -5 -474 -3 -588 7 -596 7 -6 42
-14 78 -18 81 -8 457 -61 525 -74 33 -6 54 -6 62 1 10 8 13 126 13 529 l0 518
-22 21 c-58 54 -222 145 -328 182 -122 42 -316 63 -325 36z" />
```

So, I need x and y coordinate.

I attempted to calculate the centroid using the following C# code:

```html
 public static (double cx, double cy) CalculatePathCenter(string pathData)
    {
        double xMin = double.MaxValue, xMax = double.MinValue, yMin = double.MaxValue, yMax = double.MinValue;

        // Parsing path data and extracting coordinates
        string[] commands = pathData.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < commands.Length)
        {
            string command = commands[i];
            if (command == "M" || command == "m" || command == "L" || command == "l" || command == "C" || command == "c")
            {
                // Move To, Line To, or Cubic Bezier curve command
                for (int j = 1; j < 7; j += 2)
                {
                    double x = double.Parse(commands[i + j]);
                    double y = double.Parse(commands[i + j + 1]);

                    xMin = Math.Min(xMin, x);
                    xMax = Math.Max(xMax, x);
                    yMin = Math.Min(yMin, y);
                    yMax = Math.Max(yMax, y);
                }
                i += (command == "C" || command == "c") ? 7 : 3; // Move to the next command
            }
            else if (command == "z" || command == "Z")
            {
                // Close Path command - Ignored
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        // Calculate center using bounding box coordinates
        double cx = (xMin + xMax) / 2;
        double cy = (yMin + yMax) / 2;

        return (cx, cy);
    }
```

What could be the issue with this code, and how can I fix it to correctly calculate the centroid of the SVG path? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please  clarify what exactly is the issue with this code: wrong results, not running at all?

Comment: @herrstrietzel wrong results

Comment: Your parsing function needs to convert all commands to absolute. I highly recommend using a dedicated svg path parser that covers all shorthand notations (there are quite a few of them) and converts relative to absolute commands. Or a library already including a bbox method like [SvgPathProperties](https://github.com/zHaytam/SvgPathProperties)